# Finding helpful vehicle specific communities

Tags: discussion, scope

Most of my vehicle "wrenching/hacking" has been on SAAB and VW cars and part of what has made it possible and pleasurable has been finding "real" and online communities that are knowledgable, helpful, and supportive.

I'm wondering if it would be in-scope to maintain a list, or if there is an in-scope way to help readers find more focused resources.

Comment: I suspect that SE will have a policy about this

Comment: I've been thinking about this for several days ... wouldn't this defeat the purpose of SE in the first place? The idea for SE is to consolidate the knowledge here (note, I say *knowledge* to differentiate between it and *opinion*). While the knowledge may be out there and it may be specific to a forum or website, bringing it here is far more important. Sending people to other sites defeats the main objective.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have 2 cents to contribute:

1. A car is a car is a car. Most but not all the experience you gained on V-dubs will translate to Chevys. Segregating the site into makes and models would also segregate the expertise the community has. I often answer questions that are not about a make and model that I own or have ever worked on, those users would never have gotten my 2 cents if the site was segregated by make and model.
2. I think something that would go towards what you are suggesting is have somekind of tag on people's profiles, such as make and model fo everything you've ever owned or wrenched on. If this tag is searchable, people could quickly identify who would be more reputable when weighing suggested answers. Besides, this is a mechanics site. Mechanics always love bragging about their ride. :)